# Playstation - Game and DLC different countries

Tags: ps3, psn, region-lock

Can I play a PS3 game bought in Korea with the Canadian DLC?

Here's the situation:

PlayStation 3
PSN: Canadian 
Physical game: Korean (FFXIII-2)
DLC: bought using Canadian PSN